# Creating array with unknown elements by Input them

Tags: java, arrays, do-while

I know this isn't something you are supposed to do yet but I'm still trying to figure out a way to run this loop, an letting the `arr[i]` inside it "know" about the rise of the number of elements in the array (which I declare outside of the loop because I don't want it to make a new one each time).

```
    int counter=1, note=0;

    System.out.println("Please enter characters, -1 to stop: ");

    do {
        char[] arr= new char[counter];
        for (int i=0;i<=counter;i++){

            arr[i] = s.next().charAt(0);
            if (arr[i]==-1){
                note = -1;                  
                break;
            }
            ++counter;
        } 
    } while (note>=0);
```

Comment: What do you mean?....Make it more clear.

Comment: `i <= counter` will give you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Also, incrementing `counter` inside your `for` loop will make it an infinite loop unless `counter` is 0. What the heck is character -1 supposed to mean? You are aware that you are using it as a character code, right?

Comment: Thank you for editing. The user will enter an unknown characters, and will enter -1 to stop, For example I'll enter a b c d -1, and what I want it to do is to input a,b,c,d as elements of the array (while counting the number of elements) and stop doing that when entering -1.

Answer (score 0):

From your much clearer comment, this is an example main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Input
    int amt = 0; // Amount of chars received
    List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>(); // ArrayList is easier for now
    while (input.hasNext()) { // Grabs Strings separated by whitespaces
        String token = input.next(); // Grab token
        if (token.equals("-1")) {
            break; // End if -1 is received
        } else if (token.length() != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Token not one char: " + token);
            // It seems you want only chars - this handles wrong input
        } else {
            chars.add(token.charAt(0)); // Adds the character to the list
            amt++; // Increment amt
        }
    }
    char[] array = new char[amt]; // Converting to an array
    for (int i = 0; i < amt; i++) {
        array[i] = chars.get(i); // Copies chars into array
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // Handle data here
}
```

I hope that this is correct. An input of `a b c d -1` leads to an output of `[a, b, c, d]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Input String size check I think as you will be resolved.

```
int counter=0, note=0;

System.out.println("Please enter characters, -1 to stop: ");
String input=s.nextLine();
counter=input.length();


char[] arr= new char[counter];
for (int i=0;i<counter;i++){
    arr[i] = input.charAt(i);        
}
```

and If you are using the ArrayList rather than Array is no need to worry about the size.

ArrayList is effective flexable data 
cause using add function.